# Player's Card Collection MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, dictionary, unity-game-engine

I am working on an online TCG in C# and am having trouble finding an efficient solution for storing and retrieving a player's card collection. Essentially what I want is each player in the database to have a "card collection" which I would think would be some type of dictionary that has entries of the form (card id, amount owned). I will be adding to, removing from, and editing each entry in this collection quite frequently.  I was looking into XML serialization but it seems that it would be slow for a large number of cards.  I also thought about just doing like a string of

"id1,amount1

id2,amount2"

and just splitting at ',' and newline, but I feel like that would get cumbersome editing the string.  Other's suggested to do like a new table containing fields like: userid, cardid, amount.  I am using a MySQL and am not really that familiar with database solutions like these. Is there an optimal solution to this?

Comment: Remember to be careful with stuff like distant server. The Unity engine is single threaded, which may causes issues in such case.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean.  I guess I should have mentioned I am using Photon Server and the server is the one that accesses the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely use a joining table in your database. Reading the collection can be extremely efficient if you have the right indexes and engine set up. Manipulating the collection will also be far more efficient - serialization is not cheap!

It will also serve you well if you event want to produce statistics about the composition of the average player's collection.

Comment: So having each instance of an owned card--which could mean multiple instances of the same card id--the id of the user, and the amount owned is the a good way to go about this? All in a separate table.

Comment: Yes, exactly. The key for the table is probably `(UserId, CardId)`. Ideally CardId is also the key for your `CardTypes` table, and you can join all three together when you query.

Answer (score 1):

```
[Users  ]
|UserID_|
|....   | 
|_______]

[Cards   ](all cards in the TCG)
|CardID_ |
|....    |
|________|

[Decks      ]
|DeckID_    |
|DeckUserID | -> Users.UserID 1..n
|....       |
|___________|

[DeckCards] 
|DeckID_  | -> Decks.DeckID 1..n
|CardID_  | -> Cards.CardID (1..n||1..1) to fit your needs
[_________|

[Collection   ]
|CollectionID_|
|UserID       | -> Users.UserID 1..1 to bound only one collection per user
|....         |
|_____________|

[CollectionCards] 
|CollectionID_  | -> Collection.CollectionID 1..n
|CardID_        | -> Cards.CardID (1..n||1..1) to fit your needs
[_______________|
```

You only show : Users->Collection->CollectionCards->Cards to show cards in collection of user.

You only show : Users->Deck->DeckCards->Cards to show cards in deck

I hope to be understandable...